# Java Statement, Load Data return generated keys

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement, return-value, load-data-infile

My Question might be very simple, but i can't find any answer for it.

If i execute `statement.execute("LOAD DATA ...")` will it generate return keys exactly like `INSERT` Statement,

If i do not wish to recieve any return value from the `LOAD DATA` statement, should i execute:

`statement.execute("LOAD DATA ...",Statement.NO_GENERATED_KEYS)` or is it unnecessary since `statement.execute("LOAD DATA ...")` will not return any keys in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have to use `Statement.executeUpate()` for `LOAD DATA`
2. If you do not need return values, use `Statement.executeUpdate("LOAD DATA..", Statement.NO_GENERATED_KEYS)`